# How to stop buildSrc from automatically applying groovy-all jar as a dependency?

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I have a Gradle project set up, which has a `buildSrc` module inside of it. Inside `buildSrc`, in `build.gradle`, I have the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.12'
    ...
}
```

When trying to do a build for the project, I receive the following error message:

```
2:07:13 PM: Executing external task 'build --stacktrace'...
:buildSrc:compileJava NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:compileGroovy FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:compileGroovy'.
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)
```

In the stacktrace, I see the following error:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-all is loaded in version 2.4.11 and you are trying to load version 2.4.12
    ... 15 more
```

So, when I look at the project structure, I see that the `groovy-all-2.4.11.jar` is automatically being loaded into the `buildSrc` module.

[image: Picture of buildSrc including groovy-all-2.4.11.jar]

If I remove the `compile` dependency for Groovy in `build.gradle`, it will work, but is there any way to force the module to use the version of Groovy that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle always applies the default build script to `buildSrc` project. This script contains following line:

```
compile localGroovy()
```

that is how `groovy-all-2.4.11` gets in. To override this behaviour, try setting the `resolutionStrategy`, e.g.:

```
configurations.compile {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.12'
  }
}
```

but more importantly think, why would you want to build against a groovy version that differs from one available in your plugin's runtime...